# remove namespace for a particular element

Tags: xslt

Is there any way to remove namespace for a particular element?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution.

Comment: Please provide input sample and desired output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="my:x">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="x:*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(. = namespace-uri(..))]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**removes any element from the `"my:x"` namespace and puts it into "no namespace".**

For example, when applied to the following XML document:

```
<t>
  <x:a  xmlns:x="my:x"/>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<t>
   <a/>
</t>
```

**To remove only a specific element from a specific namespace, the template overriding the identity rule must just be made more specific to match only the wanted element**.

Answer (score 0):

Your XSLT output is a fresh object (Node or text)  and you can copy or transform each element to a new one without a namespace. Assume your input uses a namespace "http://www.foo/". You create elements of the same name (and possibly the same children) without a namespace.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmnls:h="http://www.foo/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<!-- other elements and root omitted -->

    <xsl:template match="h:table">
      <table>
        <!-- copy or transform attributes and children -->
      </table>
    </xsl:table>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will create a new node with the default namespace which doesn't require a prefix and I think is what you need. [There may be more elegant ways using xsl:copy... -

UPDATE: ... and @Dmitri has shown them!

Comment: ya exaclty.. if you need to copy all the child elements , i can use <xsl:copy-of> is that right

Comment: I think xsl:copy-of will keep the namespace so I should avoid it. for xsl:copy you may be able to copy everything except namespace-uri() but you will have to look it up.

Comment: `xsl:copy` instruction also copy in scope namespace. In XSLT 2.0 you can set the `copy-namespaces` attribute.

Comment: @Alejandro thx. I was assuming XSLT1.0 as V2.0 is slow to become universal