# how to remove a part of attribut to a node in xml file using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml code:

```
<OML>    
  <bg-def xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="EX1"/>
</OML>
```

I want to remove the attribute **xmlns:xsi** and its value using XSLT, so that the result will look like this:

```
<OML>    
  <bg-def name="EX1"/>
</OML>
```

I tryied to do this with the following XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
xmlns:ex="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="ex">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"  xml:space="preserve"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="bg-def|@ xmlns:xsi"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

Before I finished to write my code, my editor warned me that:
"**W Namespace prefix xmlns has not been declared**".
When I remove the expression **:xsi** and just write **xmlns**, there is no warning more. But when I compile and execute my program, nothing happens and I don't get the expected output.
I try also to change the last line of my xslt file with this:

```
<xsl:template match="bg-def|@ name"/>
```

then the result is looking like this:

```
<OML>    
  <bg-def xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
</OML>
```

That means, the attribute **name** has been removed very well. But I want to do this with the  attribute **xmlns:xsi**. 
Can someone help me to do this please?
Thanks for any help.
Franky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following template for **bd-def** node:

```
<xsl:template match="bg-def">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Instead of

```
<xsl:template match="bg-def|@ name"/>
```

This template will create node bg-def and copy all it context nodes and attributes, but not namespaces

Check similar question:
[remove namespace for a perticular element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387571/remove-namespace-for-a-perticular-element)

**Update:**

Source file:

```
<OML>    
     <bg-def xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="EX1"/>
</OML>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
    xmlns:ex="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="ex">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" xml:space="preserve"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bg-def">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Transformation result (Saxon 6.5.5 - Xslt 1.0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><OML>    
     <bg-def name="EX1"/>
</OML>
```

Comment: @ Vitaliy, Thanks for your help, but the answer doesn't make what I want. I don't know if my question was not clear, but what I need is this output:
 `<OML>    
   <bg-def name="EX1">
  </OML>`
and the solution you gave me, provide me this
 `<OML>    
    <bg-def>EX1</bg-def>
  </OML>`. Thanks

Comment: All is ok now Vitaliy. I follow the link you gave me and I remark that I have to add **xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"** in the top of my XSLT file. Thanks again.

Comment: @Franky N - very interesting that my example gave you incorrect result - I tried it with Saxon processor and it gave me: <bg-def name="EX1"/>

Comment: @Vitaliy- I also wonder thath it doesn't function.I use the editor Oxygen with the Saxon6.5.5 processor.
Anyway, as I told you above, I could resolved the problem, just by adding **xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"** in the **<xsl:transform ...>** element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```