# Process namespaces using XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, xmlreader

I have a complex XML file with structure as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx:xxxxx:xxx:xsd:xxxx.xxx.xxx.xx">
    <Element1>
        <Element2>
            <Element2A>xxxxxx</Element2A>
            <Element2B>2012-08-29T00:00:00</Element2B>
        </Element2>
    </Element1>
</Document>
```

Now I am using XmlReader to read this XML document and process information as follows

```
XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(filename);
while (xr.Read()) 
{
   xr.MoveToElement();
   XElement node = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(xr);
   Console.WriteLine(node.Name);
}
xr.Close();
```

The problem I am facing is in the output the namespace is prefixed to the ElementName. E.g output

```
{xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx:xxxxx:xxx:xsd:xxxx.xxx.xxx.xx}Element1
```

Is there any way I can remove/ handle this as I need to do further filtering using Element names and Child names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`XElement.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.name.aspx) is not (as you might expect) a [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx), but rather an [`XName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.aspx) which has a [`LocalName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.localname.aspx) property, thus:

```
Console.WriteLine(node.Name.LocalName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Richard. However this brings me to my next problem. I am using the 'Element' method to filter through the child elements.

Since the XName isn't the simple name I expected it to be, I am not getting back any results. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually found it!

`XNamespace ns = XElement.Load(filename).GetDefaultNamespace();`

Then I can use `node.Element(ns + "ElementName").Value`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to remove the namespace. One way to remove namespace is to write c# code and other way is to use XSLT transformation as suggested in [Remove Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387571/remove-namespace-for-a-perticular-element)
-Milind