# Definitions of declared namespaces appearing in XSL output

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<e:export xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" 
    xmlns:e="http://ns.expertinfo.se/cms/xmlns/export/1.0" 
    xmlns:xinfo="http://ns.expertinfo.se/cms/xmlns/1.0">
    <e:resource id="31750" uuid="UUID-df90c0cb-f3ad-ee14-9123-02e25dedcc21" title="custom-dashboard-widget-displayed.png" />
</e:export>
```

I have the following transform -- note the definition of the namespace `xinfo`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 

    xmlns:xinfo="http://ns.expertinfo.se/cms/xmlns/1.0"
    xmlns:e="http://ns.expertinfo.se/cms/xmlns/export/1.0"  version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="e" >
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" exclude-result-prefixes="xinfo e"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//e:resource" />

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="e:resource">
         <mediaobject xinfo:version="4.0;4.1;4.2">
            <imageobject>
                <imagedata>
                    <xsl:attribute name="fileref"><xsl:value-of select="./@uuid"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="contentwidth">1014</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="xinfo:image"><xsl:value-of select="./@uuid"/></xsl:attribute>
                </imagedata>
            </imageobject>
        </mediaobject>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

This is what I want -- a few attributes with the `xinfo` namespace.

```
<mediaobject xinfo:version="4.0;4.1;4.2">
    <imageobject>
        <imagedata fileref="UUID-af013f1c-dad0-7c4b-e7df-81c3b79d55d5" contentwidth="1014" xinfo:image="UUID-af013f1c-dad0-7c4b-e7df-81c3b79d55d5"/>
    </imageobject>
</mediaobject>
```

This is what I'm getting -- a definition of the `xinfo` namespace which was declared previously:

```
<mediaobject xmlns:xinfo="http://ns.expertinfo.se/cms/xmlns/1.0"
             xinfo:version="4.0;4.1;4.2">
   <imageobject>
      <imagedata fileref="UUID-af013f1c-dad0-7c4b-e7df-81c3b79d55d5"
                 contentwidth="1014"
                 xinfo:image="UUID-af013f1c-dad0-7c4b-e7df-81c3b79d55d5"/>
   </imageobject>
</mediaobject>
```

How do I output the attribute's namespace `xinfo` without definig it again?

Comment: We really need to see a minimal but complete sample.

Comment: The output you want is not a well-formed XML document. You cannot use a prefix without binding it a namespace. No XSLT processor will produce such result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, what I wanted isn't what is possible. It happens, more often that I'd like.

I rewrote the transform to bind the namespace to a URL.

Thanks to [michael.hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k) for pointing that out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62430718/definitions-of-declared-namespaces-appearing-in-xsl-output/62433176#comment110416643_62430718):

> The output you want is not a well-formed XML document. You cannot use a prefix without binding it a namespace. No XSLT processor will produce such result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to specifically exclude the namespaces you don't want in your output with the *exclude-result-prefixes* instruction.

Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xinfo="http://ns.expertinfo.se/cms/xmlns/1.0"
  xmlns:e="http://ns.expertinfo.se/cms/xmlns/export/1.0"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xinfo e">
  ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. I still get the same output as in original question. This does beg an additional question: if I exclude the `xinfo` prefix, why is it showing in the output?

Comment: Because your node or element is part of a namespace in your original XML. See this answer for example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387571/remove-namespace-for-a-particular-element